# Communication with server when phone is in deep sleep

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I am developing a `VOIP application` that should work in a private LAN and communicate with a server.
My problems is: *how can the application receive a call/message when the phone is in deep sleep.*

In order to make the testing easier, I wrote a test application with a sticky service. The service acquires WifiLock (with `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PREF`) and `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` in its `onCreate` method.
In onStartCommand method, the service starts a thread that does the following in a loop:

- Sends a UDP packet to the server
- Writes the current time to a file
- Sleeps for 500 milliseconds

My observation is that:

- After about 8 minutes the following exception is thrown by the UDP-related code: "Operation not permitted"
- Current time is still written to file, but sometimes in intervals of a few minutes.

How is this behavior explained?

Comment: What is `deep sleep`? Are you indicating the Doze mode ?

Comment: Yes, now I read about doze mode. I understood part of the behavior: WakeLocks are ignored in doze mode and there are maintenance windows that enable the application to do something (it explains why time is written to file in intervals). I still don't understand why exception may be thrown upon sending UDP.